# Unsupported Media type error

Tags: javascript, jquery, post, cordova

Hi everyone i am working on phone gap project and using the ajax web services. I am sending request using the following code:

```
var credentials = {
                       "name": "nouman",
                       "email": "noumandilawar@gmail.com",
                       "mobile_number": 03324412764,
                       "employee_number": 4556,
                       "gender": 1,
                       "password": "1234567891234567",
                       "language": 1
                   };

            function GetMember() {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'http://192.168.1.103:8080/mazaya_cms/signup.htm',
                    //data: "{'name': 'nouman','email': 'noumandilawar@gmail.com','mobile_number': 03324412764,'employee_number': 4556, 'gender': 1,'password': '1234567891234567','language': 1}",
                    data:  JSON.stringify(credentials),
                    //data: '{"id": "nouman","name":"nouman"}',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    crossDomain: true,
                    success: OnGetMemberSuccess,
                    error: OnGetMemberError
                });
            }
            GetMember();
            function OnGetMemberSuccess(data, status) {
                alert(data+ "   "+status);
            }

            function OnGetMemberError(request, status, error) {
                alert(request+"  "+error+ "   "+status);
            }
```

I am getting error code:415 that is unsupported media type Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully solved this issue

```
var credentials = {
                "name": "nn",
                "email": "nn%40gmail.com",
                "mobile_number": 03324412764,
                "employee_number": 4556,
                "gender": 1,
                "password": "1234567891234567",
                "language": 1
            };

        $.ajax({
             url: "http://192.168.1.103:8080/mazaya_cms/signup.htm",
             type: "post",
             data: credentials,
             dataType : "json",
             success: function(request, status, error){
            alert("success "+request.status);
              },
           error:function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert("failure"+errorThrown);
              }   
        });
```